# Question regarding Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given prime $p>2$, prove that $2(p-3)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

I know that I have to use Wilson's theorem but I have no idea how to do so.

**Wilson's Theorem** : For prime $p$, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Raj, welcome to MSE. Users here prefer people who ask questions to also share their thoughts and attempts on solving the problem, rather than just a question statement or a related concept. Please edit your question and ask questions in the future accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You know that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. Thus:
$$(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
Writing $p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ and $p-2 \equiv -2 \pmod{p}$ gives:
$$(-1)(-2)(p-3)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
$$2(p-3)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
which proves the required.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question though - how were you able to replace the (p-1) and (p-2) with -1,-2 respectively.

Comment: Because $p \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, we can see that $p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.